# Was Father Mulcahy a Jesuit?

Tags: character, mash

When I see Father Mulcahy (M*A*S*H) every now and again I see him wearing a grey sweatshirt with *Loyola* (with obvious Jesuit connotations) written across it.  I was wondering, **is there any indication that he was a Jesuit?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are correct. So does the MASH wiki:

> In many episodes, Mulcahy is seen wearing a "Loyola" hoodie. This
>   makes sense in that Mulcahy was a Jesuit and Loyola is a Jesuit
>   school. In the final episode of the series, however, Mulcahy is seen
>   wearing a "Wesleyan" sweatshirt; Wesleyan University, the alma mater
>   of actor William Christopher, was affiliated with the Methodist Church
>   until 1937.

He also apparently identifies himself as a Jesuit in the series but I cannot find specific season-episode citations.